# How to configure the text in the 'Share via' dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

My app receives a share intent, how can I change the text that appears for my app in the 'share via' dialog?

Answer (score 2):

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ShareActivity"
        android:label="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Important part for you

> android:label="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY"

Answer (score -1):

Oh, so stupid...
Just change the `label` of the `activity`/`service` that will handle the intent.